# Dealing with the Cyrillic encoding in Node.Js / Express App

Tags: javascript, node.js, unicode, encoding, cyrillic

In my app a user submits text through a form's textarea and this text is passed on to the app and is then processed by [jsesc](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jsesc) library, which escapes javascript strings.

The problem is that when I type in a text in Russian, such as

```
 нам #интересны наши #идеи
```

what i get is

```
 '\u043D\u0430\u043C #\u0438\u043D\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0441\u043D\u044B \u043D\u0430\u0448\u0438 #\u0438\u0434\u0435\u0438'
```

I then need to pass this data through [FlowDock](https://github.com/flowdock/flowdock-text) to extract hashtags and FlockDock just does not recognize it.

Can someone please tell me

1) What is the need for converting it into that representation;

2) If it makes sense to convert it back to cyrillic encoding for FlowDock and for the database, or shall I keep it in Unicode and try to make FlowDock work with it?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

The complete script is:

```
result = getField(req, field);
result = S(result).trim().collapseWhitespace().s;

// at this point result = "нам #интересны наши #идеи"
result = jsesc(result, {
             'quotes': 'double'
         });

// now i end up with Unicode as above above (\u....)

var hashtags = FlowdockText.extractHashtags(result);
```

FlowDock receives the `result` which is

```
\u043D\u0430\u043C #\u0438\u043D\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0441\u043D\u044B \u043D\u0430\u0448\u0438 #\u0438\u0434\u0435\u0438
```

And doesn't extract hashtags from it...

Answer (score 2):

These are 2 representations of the same string:

```
'нам #интересны наши #идеи' ===  '\u043D\u0430\u043C #\u0438\u043D\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0441\u043D\u044B \u043D\u0430\u0448\u0438 #\u0438\u0434\u0435\u0438'
```

looks like `flowdock-text` doesn't work well with non-ASCII characters

UPD: Tried, actually works well:

```
fdt.extractHashtags('\u043D\u0430\u043C #\u0438\u043D\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0441\u043D\u044B \u043D\u0430\u0448\u0438 #\u0438\u0434\u0435\u0438');
```

You shouldn't have used escaping in the first place, it gives you string literal representation (suits for `eval`, etc), not a string.

UPD2: I've reduced you code to the following:

```
var jsesc = require('jsesc');
var fdt = require('flowdock-text');

var result = 'нам #интересны наши #идеи';

result = jsesc(result, {
             'quotes': 'double'
         });

var hashtags = fdt.extractHashtags(result);

console.log(hashtags);
```

As I said, the problem is with `jsesc`: you don't need it. It returns javascript-encoded string. You need when you are doing `eval` with concatenation to protect from code injection, or something like this. For example if you add `result = eval('"' + result + '"');`, it will work.

Comment: Thanks, but what is the difference here? Your example feeds that string to Flowdock-Text in the same format as I'm trying to get it to work and it doesn't work in my case. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The difference is, the string you have can be represented like this: `\\u043D\\u0430\\u043C #\\u0438\\u043D\\u0442...`, so it is not actually a string you want, but a javascript representation. I'm pretty sure you don't need any escaping at all

Comment: But in my example I did not have \\s i had \s... Sorry, but I don't understand...

Comment: Well, it's really hard to explain. If you add a complete script (may be simplified), which does not work, I'll just show you what's wrong

Answer (score -1):

> What is the need for converting it into that representation?

[jsesc](http://mths.be/jsesc) is a JavaScript library for [escaping JavaScript strings](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes) while generating the shortest possible valid ASCII-only output. [Here’s an online demo.](http://mothereff.in/js-escapes)

This can be used to avoid [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) and other encoding issues, or even to [avoid errors](https://twitter.com/annevk/status/380000829643571200) when passing JSON-formatted data (which may contain U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR, U+2029 PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR, or [lone surrogates](http://esdiscuss.org/topic/code-points-vs-unicode-scalar-values#content-14)) to a JavaScript parser or an UTF-8 encoder, respectively.

Sounds like in this case you don’t intend to use jsesc at all.

Comment: No I want to use it to escape things like "it\'s" and so on. But then when another app takes on the data it doesn't "understand" it.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
decodeURIComponent("\u043D\u0430\u043C #\u0438\u043D\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0441\u043D\u044B \u043D\u0430\u0448\u0438 #\u0438\u0434\u0435\u0438");
```